# Replace string text from a source file, save changes into the original file. Append using StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, replaceall

Please consider the following code. I'm not very familiar with StringBuilders or reading/writing data. I need to:

1.) Open source file

2.) Grab words and check for old string, if an old string, then append new string

3.) Use PrintWriter and Close. I am revising the following code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReplaceText {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Check command line parameter usage
    if (args.length != 4) {
      System.out.println(
        "Usage: java ReplaceText sourceFile targetFile oldStr newStr");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // Check if source file exists
    File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
      System.out.println("Source file " + args[0] + " does not exist");
      System.exit(2);
    }

    // Check if target file exists
    File targetFile = new File(args[1]);
    if (targetFile.exists()) {
      System.out.println("Target file " + args[1] + " already exists");
      System.exit(3);
    }

    // Create input and output files
    Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(targetFile);

    while (input.hasNext()) {
      String s1 = input.nextLine();
      String s2 = s1.replaceAll(args[2], args[3]);
      output.println(s2);
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();
  }
}
```

I'd also like to ask the user for the source file, old string, and new string at run time instead of using command line arguments.

I know I still need to incorporate StringBuilder. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class ReplaceText {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the source file");
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter old line");
        String oldLine = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter new line");
        String newLine = scan.nextLine();

        //scan.exit;

        /** Read one line at a time, append, replace oldLine with 
        *  newLine using a loop */


        //Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file);


        //PrintWriter that replaces file
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
        output.println(file);

        output.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?